# Medical Image Segmentation if the entire ground truth is black

Tags: image-processing, deep-learning, image-segmentation, semantic-segmentation, medical-imaging

I am new to deep learning. I am working on a CT-scan medical images. I want to use UNet architecture to predict the **image segmentation**. I have successfully implemented the UNet, however, my prediction is completely black. I think it is because there are images, for which the corresponding ground truth is black (quite a lot of images). So, I suppose it might cause a problem.

If the entire mask is black that implies there are no desired object in the **image**. An example image is below;

[image]

The below is the corresponding **ground truth**.

[image]

I am not sure how to deal with this situation. Should I remove all the (**image**, **ground truth**) pairs?
CT images are volumetric images. So when my model predict the segmentation in a new test set, it should also detect images with no desired object in it. I would appreciate if someone guide me in this.

dataset: [https://www.doc.ic.ac.uk/~rkarim/la_lv_framework/wall/index.html](https://www.doc.ic.ac.uk/%7Erkarim/la_lv_framework/wall/index.html)

Comment: My advice would be to remove those samples and see if the model gets better. What's the ratio of such images to the total samples?

Comment: @thushv89, I checked it now. I have object to no_object ratio is 4409:8386. That is, there are 8386 black images out of 12795. This is too bad.

Comment: Wow! that's pretty high. No wonder your model went haywire... Again, try removing them and see if that helps. I assume you're solving a binary classification problem here? Though I can't guarantee, I think you'd be able to reach a decent state with the ~4400 you got.

Comment: @thushv89. I am solving image segmentation problem. I will try as you have suggested. Please share if you have any other ideas. Thank you very much.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Image segmentation is more like [*pixel* classification](https://stackoverflow.com/a/33953195/1714410) than *image* classification.
Therefore, you should not look at the ratio of "blank images"/"object images", but rather the ratio of "blank *pixels*"/"object *pixels*". My guess the ratio is much more skewed towards the "blank" pixels.

This means you are dealing with severe [class imbalance](https://machinelearningmastery.com/what-is-imbalanced-classification/#:%7E:text=Imbalanced%20classification%20refers%20to%20a,is%20instead%20biased%20or%20skewed.).

[This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/58213245/1714410) lists focal loss and on-line hard negative mining as good methods for handling class imbalance.